# After hours matching

Tags: futures, after-hours-trading, order-execution

I put in an after hours sell order, well below the standard hours and after hours ask, on a liquid Dow futures security. The transaction did not complete. I looked in the ledger detail and found that a similar amount of shares had sold for 5 cents more than I had asked, well after my offer. What happened? Did the seller actually ask less than me and the market maker took the difference, or is this some weird product of first come first serve matching?